# How would I upgrade ubuntu touch to the latest development version?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have Ubuntu touch 13.10 installed on my nexus 4. I would like to update it to 14.04 don't think I should have to reinstall android and start over.

Comment: If you have a Nexus 4, you may have the option for an over-the-air update: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/ubuntu-touch-improves-system-updating

Comment: **I recommend a fresh install.** You are suggesting going from **13.10** ALPHA to **14.04** BETA. This may lose data, and/or wrongly configure some apps.